# Fans whirring at max speed and continuous POST speaker beep at boot

Tags: boot, windows-11

A little while ago, my pc started to blow all its fans at max speed and the POST speaker, the beeping thing, beeped continuously. A simple reboot fixed this so I didn't think much of it, but soon the problem grew worse and worse until the present day where it's actually a dealbreaker.
When I now boot my pc, this will happen again, but a restart doesn't fix it. I have to restart it a couple times and pray every time and it'll function normally, but it usually takes about 5 reboots, most of which are forced by holding down the power button which causes Windows to go into recovery mode and after that it usually works normally.

I couldn't find anyone having had a similar experience online anywhere, so I decided to post this here.

My specs are as follows:
Windows 11 (not sure about the build, will update if necessary)
Gigabyte Gaming X Z390 motherboard
Intel Core i9-9900kf CPU
Nvidia GeForce RTX 3060 Ti
Corsair Vengeance 32gb 3600mhz DDR4 RAM
Corsair RM850 powersupply

P.s. it should also be noted that this issue does not occur while in the BIOS or recovery mode/advanced reboot which leads me to believe this is somehow related to Windows.
P.p.s. the pc works fine besides this issue even while the fans are whirring.

Comment: I am currently on an Ubuntu 21.10 installation booting from a USB and I am not having any of these problems which once again leads me to believe that this is somehow caused by Windows.

Comment: Another breakthrough has been made, the fans and the speaker do eventually stop. It seems to be a couple minutes after the first boot that it stops doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a hardware fault. If you have spares, replace them and see if it continues. Swap the dimms around and clean the contacts. Check with your m/b manual as to what the continuous beep means.

Comment: You think the dimms are faulty?

Comment: Of course we don't. But try stripping out as much as you can, and reset & clean all cards & memory sticks,

Answer (score 0):

How long is the beep? Long or short?

Turn the pc off. Take the RAM module(s) out. Clean as much as possible with compressed air. Put the RAM module(s) back in. If you have more than one, try putting them in one at a time and starting the pc each time to see if the problem occurs.

> Memory Error - Continuous long beep

> Memory not correctly installed - Continuous short beep

https://www.gigabyte.com/Support/FAQ/816

Take everything out including hard drive, RAM, graphics card, etc. Leave only the CPU installed. Disconnect the keyboard, mouse, and anything else connected externally. Then boot up. If behavior is normal for your mother board (correct error beeps, etc.), put in the RAM and test again. If normal, add graphics card. If normal, add more components; rinse and repeat. Sooner or later you'll connect something that will cause a problem, and you'll know what it is.

Comment: It doesn't stop, it just keeps going.

Comment: @PlanetTeamSpeak I edited the answer above